# Can't store a .pdf file in a blob in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob

So I am trying to upload a PDF file into a mySQL blob, the table row gets inserted but in the fileContent which is the mediumBlob type it appears always as [BLOB 0 B] and when the file is downloaded, it is downloaded with 0 bytes. Ive echoed $content and it shows the special characters of the pdf file.

```
$erro = '';
$tipo = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text'] !== null && isset($_POST['userID']))
    {
        if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/',$_POST['text']) && strlen($_POST['text']) < 15 ) 
        {

            if (substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3, 3) == "pdf" && $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000) 
            {

              if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
              {
                $erro = "Problema: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
                $tipo = 'erro';
              } 
              else 
              {
                  $_FILES["file"]["name"] = $_POST['text'].'.pdf';
                  $erro = "Ficheiro guardado com sucesso.";
                  $tipo = 'sucesso';
               }
            }
            else 
            {
               $erro = "Apenas .PDF com menos de 10 Mb são permitidos!";
               $tipo = 'erro';
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            $erro = "Nome inválido";
            $tipo = 'erro';
        }

        if ($tipo == 'sucesso')
        {
            $content = $db->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

            if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
            {
                $smt = $db->prepare('INSERT into uploads (userRefID,fileName,fileType,fileSize,fileContent,uploadDate) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)');
                $smt->bind_param('issibs', $_POST['userID'], $_FILES["file"]["name"], $_FILES["file"]["type"], $_FILES["file"]["size"], $content ,date(c));
                $smt->execute();
                $smt->close();
            }
        }



    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many bytes approximately are in this blob?

Comment: The MySQL setting `max_allowed_packet` will have a say in this. By default it's set to 16MB, so that's your maximum query length.

Comment: the file Im uploading has 131Kb. How come the length is higher than that?

Comment: Not the root cause of the problem, but I don't think you need to `real_escape_string` the contents before passing them as you are using `bind_param` which handles this for you.

Comment: I tried without it, same results. Now Ive tested a 3Kb PDF, same results....

Comment: Did you consider storing files on filesystem instead blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#110201) you should not pass the blob directly in `bind_param`, but with `send_long_data`.

From the documentation of [`send_long_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php) here's an example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null);
$fp = fopen("messages.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(0, fread($fp, 8192));
}
fclose($fp);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I tried using that now. I obtain the same result [BLOB 0 B]

Comment: The first parameter to `send_long_data` is the parameter number in the SQL statement. So it should be 4 here, not 0.